# Merging a Detached Head?

Tags: git, git-merge

So I kind of messed up royally and created a detached head because I wanted to go back to a previous version of my code. Problem is: now I can't push anything because my main branch is a detached head. If I try to merge the branches then it gets rid of the head and anything on it. How do I get the commits on my detached head back onto the master branch? I heard about this code: git merge HEAD@{1} but I was scared to try it without confirmation because I was afraid of what would happen. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Are you using TortoiseGit by any chance? I've noticed that I sometimes get into a detached state, and running the switch command on the desired branch puts it back to a good, attached state again. The same might go for the command line, as well.

Comment: Don't be afraid of `git merge HEAD@{1}`. The great thing about Git is that you can always try things out locally, and then do hard resets to undo what you just did. If you don't like the result of `git merge HEAD@{1}`, then you can undo it by using `git reset --hard HEAD^`.

Answer (score 15):

> because my main branch is a detached head

No, that’s not correct. A detached HEAD is when you have checked out a commit that is *not* a branch. So by definition, you are not on a branch if you have a detached HEAD.

I would suggest you to create a branch from your current (detached) HEAD, so you don’t lose any information but can move around freely again:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

After that, you will be on a non-detached HEAD again, on `newbranch`, and you should be able to check out other branches and merge `newbranch` in some other branch if necesary.

Comment: Oh okay. That makes sense. I was wondering what made the detached HEAD different than other branches. So I've made the new branch. Now what would I do?

Comment: The key is to `merge` your new branch into the existing branch where you originally meant to commit to, as mentioned in the last sentence of this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Do the following steps to resolve the **DETACHED HEAD** issue:

1. Checkout to that detached branch: `git checkout detachedBranchHash`
2. Create a new branch: `git checkout -b newBranchName`
3. Checkout to your main/master branch: `git checkout master`
4. Merge your new branch with master branch: `git merge newBranchName`

How to know my detachedBranchHash? => Type `git log` and you will see there. You can type the whole hash or the first 6-7 characters.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that you didn't make any additional commits once you entered a detached head state, you can return to your previous commit (the one that is the tip of the last branch you were on) by using the following command:

```
git checkout <name-of-branch>
```

Comment: If you HAVE added commits, you should do what one of the other answer suggests and run git checkout -b newbranch instead. That will keep your commits.